# What does "stick to one's guns" mean there?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

"Any advance on fifty thousand dollars? No advance on fifty thousand? No advance gentlemen? Going at fifty thousand, the wreck of the brig Flying Scud - going - going - gone!"...
At the door of the exchange I found myself alongside of the short middle-aged gentleman, who had made an appearance, so vigorous and so brief, in that great battle.
"Congratulate you, Mr. Dodd," he said. "You and your friend **stuck to your guns** nobly."
"No thanks to you, sir," I replied, "running us up a thousand at a time, and tempting all speculators in San Francisco to come and have a try."...
(*The Wrecker* by R. L. Stevenson and L. Osbourne, chapter ix-x, published 1892)

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stick-to-guns

Comment: I expect he googled 'stick to your guns' !

Comment: I would discourage experienced users from downvoting this question or making snide comments. The question is asking about the meaning of the phrase in context, not just the definition of the phrase. We are asked to be kind to new contributors. Sarcasm and disapproval don't help. Instead, you can help by either editing the question or providing education about the use of the site in your comments.

Comment: @ dwilli - Yes, thank you, I agree. Realizing the downvoting I was primarily disappointed. I had read the definition of "stick to your guns" in my OELD - it reads *stick to your guns: to refuse to change your mind about sth even when other people are trying to persuade you that you are wrong*. I think this definition is open to some interpretations in this context, so I asked this question.

Comment: Where did you find this? (to be put after Stuart F's comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the context of the conversation we can infer that the people talking have been at an auction. The telltale phrase is "Going, going, gone", which is what auctioneers stereotypically say to close a bidding session on an item in an auction. Someone speaks to Mr. Dodd and congratulates him, which tells us that Mr. Dodd was the person who won the bidding. When he then says, "You and your friends stuck to your guns", he's saying that he and his friends persisted in their effort to win the privilege of buying the wreck of the brig, Flying Scud.

The phrase, "to stick to one's guns" has an obvious military connotation to it, suggesting that the person doesn't run away, but keeps firing their guns in the face of danger.